# CellAddress add one column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an active cellAddress, how do I get it to display the active cellAddress + 1 column

```
myFormula = Replace(myFormula, "XXX", cellAddress)
```

Comment: `ActiveCell.Offset(,1).Address`?

Comment: `myFormula = Replace(myFormula, "XXX", Range(cellAddress).Offset(, 1).Address(0, 0))`?

Comment: Thangs a lot freinds, just what I needed